# Redirecting to a relative URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

My problem is that I want to redirect via JavaScript to a directory above.

**My code:**

```
location.href = (location.href).substr(0, (location.href).lastIndexOf('folder'))
```

The URL looks like this:

`example.com/path/folder/index.php?file=abc&test=123&lol=cool`

The redirect affect just this:

`example.com/path/&test=123&lol=cool`

But want to have this:

`example.com/path/`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 924, accepted):

You can do a relative redirect:

```
window.location.href = '../'; //one level up
```

or

```
window.location.href = '/path'; //relative to domain
```

Comment: see why you should use `window.location.replace` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery/506004#506004

Comment: When you want to simulate a link, you should use `window.location.href`. You should only use `window.location.replace` when you want to simulate an http redirect (thus not generating a history item).

Comment: By the way, `document.location` was intended as a read-only property. It is safer to use `window.location`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascript).

Comment: I found using `window.location.href = '../'` redirected to the root of the site and not "one level up" as expected. When the current page is "www.example.com/customers/list" I needed to use `'./'`. I guess this is because "list" is not considered as a directory level.

Comment: @MarcusCunningham, in your example, the directory is /customers/ - so "one level up" is www.example.com/. Now if your example URL was www.example.com/customers/list/ - it would redirect you to www.example.com/customers/

Answer (score 18):

If you use `location.hostname` you will get your domain.com part. Then `location.pathname` will give you /path/folder. I would split `location.pathname` by / and reassemble the URL. But unless you need the querystring, you can just redirect to `..` to go a directory above.

Comment: My browser barks when I go *location.path* and it seems only to recognize *location.pathname*. Hints?

Comment: location.path is incorrect, it should be location.hostname. I've added an edit to the post to fix this.

Answer (score 16):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign

- `window.location.assign("../");` // one level up
- `window.location.assign("/path");` // relative to domain

Comment: the "/path" doesnt work for assign. It would not include the domain but just try to open "/path"

Answer (score 12):

redirect to `../`

Comment: If your app is hosted in a sub-uri and the app doesn't know the sub-uri path. If you are at your apps root and you do ../ the app won't know how to get back to its root. For example, the same app is hosted at http://example.com/myapp/ and http://other.example.com/app2/

Answer (score 6):

`<a href="..">no JS needed</a>`

`..` means parent directory.

Comment: That requires a click or some other user-initiated navigation.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question but just to provide more information, this is how urls work:

```js
window.location.href = 'https://domain/path';   // absolute
window.location.href = '//domain/path';         // relative to current schema
window.location.href = 'path';                  // relative to current path
window.location.href = '/path';                 // relative to domain
window.location.href = '../';                   // one level up
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm trying to redirect my current web site to other section on the same page, using JavaScript.  This follow code work for me:

```
location.href='/otherSection'
```

Answer (score 2):

try following js code

```js
location = '..'
```