# Javascript window.location.href - Refreshes page instead of redirecting

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser

I'm using window.location.href to redirect my browser and I am not sure why one works and one doesn't.  When I use a relative link, it refreshes the current page.  When I use the full url it redirects.  The page I'm on and the Process.aspx page are on the same directory level.  So I should just be able to have a relative link?  When I do that though it just reloads the current page I'm on.  What basic idea am I missing about window.location.href?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $( "button" )
        .button();
    $("#cancel")
        .click(function( event ) {
            alert("click");

            //Below Line Doesn't work
            window.location.href = "/Process.aspx";

            //Below Line Does work
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:65215/Process.aspx";
    });
});
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens?

Comment: Prefer explanation of expected output VS actual output to "doesn't work"

Comment: Without being able to test... remove the `/`..?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit and clarify. :(
@Stefan, the / doesn't change it.

Comment: *"it just reloads the current page I'm on"*... sure but what is the URL of that page?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript/506004#506004 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655065/redirecting-to-a-relative-url-in-javascript

Comment: @ComFreek, I removed the alert and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @WesleyMurch, http://localhost:65215/AddTask.aspx would be the other URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Mozilla Developer Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location), `href` is the entire URL of the page. The only relative property in that list is `path`, which is relative to the host or the domain of the page.

You may also want to look at using the `reload` or `replace` method. See [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript/506004#506004)

Comment: Replace would simulate a redirect, but I don't want to simulate a redirect?  I want to just have a relative path?  Would my only option then be to parse the current location string?

Comment: I think parsing the current location string would be the best option in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat of an edge case, but this problem can also occur if you add event listeners to container divs with anchor tags in them and you want to make each container div, rather than just the anchor tag, clickable and then redirect to the link contained within the anchor tag's `href attribute`. In this case, you want to include `event.preventDefault()` to prevent this behavior.

**Vanilla JS**

```
document.getElementById("myAnchorDiv").addEventListener("click", function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

    //get url 
    URL = ...

   //Below Line should now work
   window.location.href = URL;
});
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#myAnchorDiv").on("click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //get url 
    URL = ...

    //Below Line should now work
    window.location.href = URL;

 });
```

If you want, you can of course combine the last two lines of code into just one line of code, i.e. something like `window.location.href = [your URL];`

Answer (score 1):

Try: `location.href = location.origin + "/Process.aspx";`

Answer (score 0):

you can try a hack that only refresh the page, you can implement `onclick="location.href='wherever'"` and a second `href="/Process.aspx"` `onclick` will be fired first and `href` will take you back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.location = window.location.protocol + 
                  '//' +
                  window.location.hostname +
                  window.location.pathname;
```