# pass parameter with url ajax to controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have an url in ajax like this:

```
<html>
<header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</header>
<body>
<?php 

        echo("<pre>");
        echo "Hello: <span style='color:red'>".$user_data['user'];
        echo("</pre>"); 
        echo "<button  id='play' id_user = '".$user_data['id']."' user = '".$user_data['user']."'>Chơi game</button>";
?>

<script>
$("#play").click(function(){
    var user_id  = $(this).attr('id_user');
    var user = $(this).attr('user');
    window.location=  "<?php echo site_url('wellcome?user_id='.$user_data['id'].'&user='.$user_data['user']); ?>";

    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i redirect to `welcome` Controller with 2 parameters then it shows a `404 error`. How should i do pass that parameter to controller `welcome`? Thanks all!

Comment: That's not Ajax.  I'm not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want call controller `wellcome` and pass parametter in it.

Comment: You are not calling a controller, you are moving away from the page. You want somehting like http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

**Things to check** for the redirect (not ajax) you are trying to do:

- use window.location.***href***
- are you certain, there's something at `wellcome?...` (welcome typically has a single letter l ?
- check in HTML source view, what get's generated behind the equal sign. Does it look like a reasonable URL path?
- obviously, you attempt a ***relative*** path, see [further advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1655079/444255) how to do that.
- Arguably better, change to an absolute path, using PHP `$_SERVER` Variables to glue it together, or at least start with a leading `//` (path and protocol-relative to your page)