# How to redirect to a new page in the same domain

Tags: javascript

I won't know at design time what the domain is in. I need to have the enduser have the choice to click a button to go to the default page within that domain.

I have tried the following but it is not reloading the new page:

```
location.assign(window.location.pathname.replace("availability.aspx", 
 "default.aspx"));
location.reload(true);
```

TIA ...

Comment: Simply setting window.location.href should do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting to a relative URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655065/redirecting-to-a-relative-url-in-javascript)

Comment: "I need to have the enduser have the choice to click a button to go to the default page within that domain." Sounds very much like an `<a>` tag, the `href` attribute can be relative to the page it's on--and there's an example on the possible duplicate benvc mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `document.location = "default.aspx";`