# How to add relative path with JS for 2 level

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect from this page:

http://mywebpage/hotel/suite/availability/default.html

to:

http://mywebpage/hotel/suite/costs/default.html

I am using this to redirect:

```
window.location.href = "../../costs/default.html"
```

I need it to be a relative path, but I cant figure how to

Comment: That's already a relative path. But is only one level away, not 2, just remove one `../`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting to a relative URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655065/redirecting-to-a-relative-url-in-javascript)

Comment: @Triby that one is for one or domain path, but i need it to be for 2 levels up, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Beastbeast Have you evaluated Triby's suggestion? It matches your example, so maybe your example is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

window.location.href = "../../costs/default.html"

Is working, apparently it was an error on the server wich didnt allow the app to refresh that line