# Button clicked to redirect to parent URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, semantic-ui, react-router-dom

The application is running on page: `http://localhost:3000/login` and when a button is clicked it should redirect to `http://localhost:3000/`.

So this is how I've tried:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';

...


<Button onClick={() => <Redirect to="/" />}>
     Go home
</Button>
```

it doesn't work. What is missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655065/redirecting-to-a-relative-url-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

Since you intend to move out of the app. Why not try

```
onClick={()=> window.location.replace('/')}
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for! something quick that fixes the problem without importing other stuff

Comment: Happy coding ;)

Comment: Causes a page refresh and also overwrites browser history. Probably not what you want. @0stone0's comment is what you need.

Comment: Since the OP tagged `reactjs` and `react-router`, is this the preferred way to redirect a user?

Comment: To my understanding, the react app isn't running under  localhost:3000/ but http://localhost:3000/login

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Handling onClick

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

....

const history = useHistory();
<Button onClick={() => {history.push("/");}}>
 Go home
</Button>
```

Solution 2:

Using button as Link

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

...

<Button as={Link} to="/">
 Go Home
<Button/>
```

Both of the solution works, however in second case, you might need to handle the styling of the text of Button