# window onload function issue

Tags: javascript, html

```
window.onload = prepareButton;

function prepareButton() {
  document.getElementById('slist').onclick = function() {
    window.location = "students";
  }
}
```

Once I click on a `slist` element which happens to be a `<p>` tag structured like this

```
<p type="button" id="slist" class="active">Student List</p>
```

It keeps the page reloading forever, I don't know why.

Comment: When you say "reloading forever", do you mean it gets keeps reloading over and over again? or that the new page never loads?

Comment: Are you aware that this code will replace the last URL segment by `students`? Is that what you need to do?

Comment: Nothing in this code should cause infinite/repeated reloading. We can't help without a [mcve].

Comment: I tried to help you but was downvoted, so I've removed it. I hope you find a solution. Because the one I gave worked for me.

Comment: actually the reload happened becayse of something else, i fixed that... still thanks a lot guys

Comment: @James The code in the question worked just as well. Your answer didn't explain why changing it would make any difference (and in fact, they didn't made a difference.) As expected (and confirmed by OP), the problem was elsewhere. Those downvotes seem more than justified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign a whole URL [or path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1655081/14909980) to [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location), not just a word:

```js
window.onload = prepareButton;

function prepareButton() {
  document.getElementById('slist1').onclick = function() {
    window.location = "stackoverflow.com/questions";
  }
  document.getElementById('slist2').onclick = function() {
    window.location = "/questions";
  }
  document.getElementById('slist3').onclick = function() {
    window.location = "../..";
  }
}
```

```html
All these buttons will take you to the StackOverflow questions overview.
<p type="button" id="slist1">Using the whole URL</p>
<p type="button" id="slist2">Using an absolute path</p>
<p type="button" id="slist3">Using a relative path</p>
```

(Sorry - for some reason it doesn't work inside a StackSnippet …)