# Changing browser window shows popup blocker

Tags: javascript, html, web

I using this script of code where I am detecting OS of user and if it is a mobile OS then I am displaying another window.

```js
function getOS() {
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent,
    platform = window.navigator?.userAgentData?.platform || window.navigator.platform,
    macosPlatforms = ['Macintosh', 'MacIntel', 'MacPPC', 'Mac68K','iPad'],
    windowsPlatforms = ['Win32', 'Win64', 'Windows', 'WinCE'],
    iosPlatforms = ['iPhone', 'iPod'],
    os = null;
    
    if (macosPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {

    } else if (iosPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
        location.replace("mobile.html")
    } else if (windowsPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
  
    } else if (/Android/.test(userAgent)) {
        location.replace("mobile.html")
    } else if (/Linux/.test(platform)) {

    }        
    return os;
}
getOS()
```

This script is in the start of document inside the head tag.
when I am running the hosted website in mobile. It is showing a dialog box that shows the text " Do you want to allow popups from this page". I think this is because of the fact that I am opening a different window. I tried using `window.open()` function instead of `location.replace()` because I thought that would help but it is of no use.
Can anyone help me figure out how to not show that dialog at default because it is ruining overall website experience.

Comment: You probably can't do anything programmatically as pop-up behaviour is governed by browser settings.

Comment: location.replace does not open a new window. Sounds strange

Comment: it does show the window but after allowing the pop ups

Answer (score 1):

I would set `location.href` rather than using `replace`.  You can use a relative URL when setting the `href`.  See [Redirecting to a relative URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655065/redirecting-to-a-relative-url-in-javascript) for more details.

```js
function getOS() {
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent,
    platform = window.navigator?.userAgentData?.platform || window.navigator.platform,
    macosPlatforms = ['Macintosh', 'MacIntel', 'MacPPC', 'Mac68K','iPad'],
    windowsPlatforms = ['Win32', 'Win64', 'Windows', 'WinCE'],
    iosPlatforms = ['iPhone', 'iPod'],
    os = null;
    
    if (macosPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {

    } else if (iosPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
        location.href = "/mobile.html"
    } else if (windowsPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
  
    } else if (/Android/.test(userAgent)) {
        location.href = "/mobile.html"
    } else if (/Linux/.test(platform)) {

    }        
    return os;
}
getOS()
```